# Give input to lambda function through cloud watch event

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

I have a cloud watch event that triggers a lambda function every day. I need to send a string as input to the lambda function that this cloud watch event will be triggering. I am using Python-3.X as my coding language.

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Is the string you want to send fixed or variable? If variable when does it vary? You could write this variable to DynamoDB and then the Lambda function, when invoked on a schedule, would read it from DynamoDB (or S3 or some other persistent store). Or you could even simply update the Lambda function configuration (store the value as an environment variable in the Lambda function config) whenever the value changes.

Comment: @jarmod It is a static string

Answer (score 3):

you will get the input inside the `event` you can check the following link for more [clarification](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-programming-model-handler-types.html)

When configuring the targets from `cloudwatch` rules you will find `configure input` option on the right part of the console page and then you can choose **JSON** input 
also you can check this [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/RunLambdaSchedule.html) for clarification

Comment: We will be defining this while configuring the CloudWatch, right? And once it triggers the lambda function, the lambda function will get this json input as event. Correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: you will be using the `event` object inside the lambda code to get the sent json text
and inside the cloudwatch rule you will trigger the lambda and send the json text in `configure input` > `Constant (JSON text)`

Comment: Yes I get that. What I am asking is that the JSON text will be sent from the CloudWatch, right?

Comment: Okay. Got it. Thanks

Comment: @TeeKay yes it will be sent from the cloudwatch in the event

Comment: Okay. I will try to implement it.

Comment: Hey! Can you give an example of how to configure it through Terraform?